# Failed to generate Violations(post build actions) using Job-DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to convert a non-Jenkins DSL into DSL.The problem here is the **violations** part is missing.

```
job('example') {
        publishers {
            violations(50) {
               sourcePathPattern('source pattern')
               fauxProjectPath('faux path')
               perFileDisplayLimit(51)
               checkstyle(10, 11, 10, 'test-report/*.xml')
               findbugs(12, 13, 12)
               jshint(10, 11, 10, 'test-report/*.xml')
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean missing here? Configuration is lost for the generated job?

Comment: @Tim:yes.I don't see violations in my job configuration

Comment: What plugin are you using? What version of the plugin? Also, what version of job-dsl plugin are you using?

Comment: hi @BitwiseMan : Job-DSL 1.39 ; violations 0.7.11

Comment: Dont test it with this version, it works for me if I use job dsl 1.49-SNAPSHOT  (latest dev version) and violations 0.7.11, so try to upgrade job dsl to latest may solve your problem.

Comment: @Tim : I will try that.Thanks :)